# How can I change the properties.settings c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form (winforms) and in that form I have a sidebar.
In the properties window of the sidebar I have clicked on `ApplicationSettings` and then on `PropertyBindigs`, in the dialog that appears i see all the property's of the sidebar. in the textbox right of `visible` i gave it a name 'SelectedVisible'.

In `Solution explorer` on the name of my project, I right click and select `properties` now I see the setting and indeed I see the one I've created (SelectedVisible) as a `bool` with the value `True`.

In the form I have a `combobox` with the items 'True' and 'False', the idea is that if I select 'false' the sidebar disappears on run-time, if I select 'true' the side bar appears. I made the following code for that

```
if(comboBox1.Text=="False")
{
     Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedVisible = False;
}
else if(comboBox1.Text=="True")
{
     Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedVisible = True;
}
```

the `Settings.Default.Save();` is in the click event of a button

Now the problem:
Now mather what I do the setting stays on 'True', I've tried to change the code from True to "True" and False to "False" but every time I check the property of my application I see that nothing has changed.

2nd problem:
If I manually change the value of 'SelectedVisible' and then run my app, the sidebar is there even when the value is false even in the property of the sidebar.

get my confusion?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your condition to:

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals("True")) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried and for me it works fine.

The problem is the condition, try this:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedVisible = bool.Parse(comboBox1.Text);
```

To be on the safe side, you can use TryParse:

```
bool value;
if(bool.TryParse(comboBox1.Text, out value))
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedVisible = value;
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works. the mistake a made was to write it in the wrong section.